# Branch.getInstance().setIdentity("Test_client_id") : setIdentity method is not working

Tags: android, branch, git-branch, branch.io

I have integrated the Branch android sdk to my app i am passing some value to    `setIdentity("Test_client_id")` method which i trying to fetch from the Branch dashboard by using `${(user_data.developer_identity)!}` but not getting any data. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d64rD.png)

```
branch.initSession(branchInitializer, getIntent().getData(), this);
Branch.getInstance().setIdentity("-thesun");
```

Branch sdk version : 3.2.0

For Reference i have attached the Branch dashboard screenshot. In install event the Developer_id is coming null but after that for reinstall the Developer_id is coming

Comment: Have a look at the answer to the following question and see if it helps in any way, [How to implement the Referral system with Branch.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181681/how-to-implement-the-referral-system-with-branch-io).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement the Referral system with Branch.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39181681/how-to-implement-the-referral-system-with-branch-io)